# Readmore.js not working inside Bootstrap 3 Modal

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using **[Readmore.js](http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/)** in my page to hide extra content. This  working fine everywhere except NOT WORKING inside Bootstrap Modal.

Here is my Example **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kcS2N/44/)**

You will see there are some text with Show More link. When I click on that Show more it shows more text which were hidden. 
But Same thing I did inside a Modal(click Modal Button) but it's not working there. I hope I added everything correctly but I am not getting why it not coming inside a modal. How I can make it work inside a modal.

I need this readmore.js to use very badly too. So any Help will save me.

**JS**

```
$('.show-more').readmore({
        maxHeight: 112,
        speed: 300,
        moreLink: '<a href="#" class="btn btn-link" style="display: block; width: auto; padding: 0px;text-align: left; margin-top: 10px;">Show more</a>',
        lessLink: '<a href="#" class="btn btn-link" style="display: block; width: auto; padding: 0px;text-align: left; margin-top: 10px;">Show Less</a>'
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `show` and `shown` bootstrap3 events, e.g:

```
var opts = {
    maxHeight: 112,
    speed: 300,
    moreLink: '<a href="#" class="btn btn-link" style="display: block; width: auto; padding: 0px;text-align: left; margin-top: 10px;">Show more</a>',
    lessLink: '<a href="#" class="btn btn-link" style="display: block; width: auto; padding: 0px;text-align: left; margin-top: 10px;">Show Less</a>'
};

$('.show-more').readmore(opts);

$('.modal').one('show.bs.modal', function () {
    //for styling purpose only
    $(this).find('.show-more').css({overflow: "hidden", maxHeight: opts.maxHeight});
}).one('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    //initialize plugin once modal shown
    $(this).find('.show-more').readmore(opts);
});
```

You need to initialize plugin once the modal is opened the first time.

### -DEMO jsFiddle-